# User enters letters one by one, final product should fill the elipses

Tags: python-3.x

```
#/r/AskOuija

thing1 = ("1: My mom always told me to ....")
thing2 = ("2: I don't .... ")
thing3 = ("3: Go .... yourself")

print("1: My mom always told me to ....")
print("2: I don't .... ")
print("3: Go .... yourself")

choice = int(input("Please enter the number of the chosen one: "))

if choice == 1:
    print("1: My mom always told me to ....")
    print(thing1[27:32])
    one = input("Enter a letter [Type done when done]: ")
    one = input("Enter a letter [Type done when done]: ")
    one = input("Enter a letter [Type done when done]: ")
    one = input("Enter a letter [Type done when done]: ")
    print(thing1)
    if one == "done":
        print(thing1)
```

User enters letters one by one, final product should fill the elipses

User enters letters one by one, final product should fill the elipses

User enters letters one by one, final product should fill the elipses

User enters letters one by one, final product should fill the elipses

Maybe this is out of my scope, im not even sure

Comment: Whats the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

```
#/r/AskOuija
# All phrases put into a nice list
phrases = ["0: My mom always told me to ....", "1: I don't .... ", "2: Go .... yourself"]

# For every phrase inside phrases, go ahead and print the phrase
for phrase in phrases:
   print(phrase)

# Now the user inputs their choice (range of 0 to 3)
choice = int(input("Please enter the number of the chosen one: "))

# Spit back out the selected choice
print(phrases[choice])
print("....")
res = ""

# Now loop four times and concatenate the chars inputted by the user
for i in range(4):
  temp = input("Enter a letter [Type done when done]: ")

  # Gotta check just incase some hooligan tried to enter more than one char
  while len(temp) > 1:
    print("Re-enter a letter. Your last entry was too long")
    temp = input("Enter a letter [Type done when done]: ")
  res += temp

print(phrase[choice].replace("....", "res"))
```

Now you don't have to repeat the output chunk per phrase and you can just make it super dynamic. Hopefully this makes sense. I kinda cleaned up your code. Kinda had fun with it haha.

Also for future reference the function you're looking for is *.replace()* which i used.

Heres [more information on the function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

Comment: Code looks amazing, but it tackles things I haven't learnt, the whole reason I wanted to do this project was too secure what I have already learned, do you think you could write this code super beginner friendly? I think the program I wanted to make was out of my scope to begin with